# Best way to display swiftyjson parsed data?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

After already having parsed my data through swiftyjson I am looking to display the parsed information in a uitableview. Let's say I have a list of names that I parsed out of the json file. I would like those names to display each in their own respective cells to allow the user to view them all.

I would also assume that if they selected the selected cells which are being displayed strings now after being parsed that I can actually have those stored into a core data object storing them as returnable strings? The thing is I used the .append function onto an array that I created we'll call `names = [String]()` to actually allow the values to actually come in order for the cells.

But when doing this I noticed a huge spike in cpu usage doing this as it keeps appending them in order lets say first name is matt second name is john and so forth then it creates a new situation of the array every time. so the first time it reads just matt then the next println would print out matt, john then the next one prints out matt, john, tom and so forth until the list of json names is completed.

If I have 500 names or more it takes the cpu awhile to process all those names into the array. I know there has to be another way but all references I see all use the .append method. So my code would be     names.append(Name). Name is a parsed string from swiftyjson. From there I am actually able to populate the tableview which is fine it displays correctly in the end but it takes the device awhile to populate as it first needs to process adding all 500 names each time the parse is called. I am hoping to allow the 500 names be rechecked every time in case new ones have been added. This all stores currently as a local json file already.

The code I am using is below I can figure out the UItableview part but it's more a question of whether appending an array is the best and most efficient way of displaying the parsed data from swiftyjson.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("List", ofType: "json")
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)
for (key, subJson) in json["array"] {
    if let Name = subJson["Name"].string {
        NameList.append(Name)
        println(NameList)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the Swift `map` function is more effective

```
…
let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)
var nameList = [String]()
if let subJson = json["array"] as [Dictionary<String,NSObject>]? {
  nameList = subJson.map { $0["name"] as! String }
}
```

Comment: My issue is more with the hangup of the app actually appending the 500 names into an array 1 by 1. Would this map function change that? Or is there a better way to view all the json data in a tableview?

Comment: basically the map function does the same as the loop but in a more effective way. To avoid blocking the main thread consider to load the data in a background thread

Comment: Aside from appending an array is there another possible way for me to get the readout directly from the json file to the tableview? All I ever see are examples of appends but as appending an array can take a bit of time every time it checks for new data it seems rather inefficient. I do like the idea of mapping though which does seem much more efficient.

Comment: you have to map the data anyway, because the table view requires an array of printable objects – an array of String or Dictionary / custom class with appropriate key / property

Comment: So I guess that answers both questions then. I was hoping tableview could actually pull the info somehow directly. Maybe If I make it so that I parse the data 1 time into the array once a week? I was hoping to have it done regularly. But I don't want to have the user have to wait for the array to reappend every time to recheck for newer data.

Comment: Your mapping function gives me an error. It states that the JSON isn't convertible to a [Dictionary<String, NSOBject>]?

Comment: it's only an example, I don't know what `contentsOfFile` returns and what the data structure of the json object is. Maybe swiftyjson returns something that's not mappable. Cocoa has a built-in class to serialize JSON

Comment: contentsOfFile returns just the numbers associated with the json objects and array its the untranslated form of the json

Comment: contentsOfFile returns an NSData object and the JSON initializer converts the data to something. You have to find out the type structure. If the "array" object is the untranslated json, I recommend to use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert it to Swift collection types which are mappable. I guess it's still faster as using the loop

Comment: I just wish there was some way i could avoid using the array method. The only other way I could see making it without an array is to make a .swift file containing the same database? I just really don't want to have to redo the database like that. My issue I guess comes from appending the data into an array. Using swifty-json I was wondering if there is a way to get it into the array without appending it every time?

Comment: Other suggestion: save the data as property list, preferred with String types only. The deserialization is pretty fast and you have the benefit of the modern generic Swift functions

Comment: What if I wanted to cross check integers my list has a lot of ints that I use for references like this person belongs to this section and that section is rating number 1. I would imagine it would make things easier for me to translate the whole code in swift in relational terms like saying if this person doesn't belong to this section {}. I am still working out how I would even do that with the parsed data. Basically I am going to be running a whole bunch of checks to make sure each individual belongs in the list, all of which would be displayed in a tableview.

Comment: Am I actually able to do checks with swifty-json check that the `if 1 = 1 {

//code here}`

Comment: If I go with a property list instead am I able to do the same kind of checks as the comment above?